# joining two fields in database to a single dropdown in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have two dropdown fields vehicle and vehicleBrand. There is a table for vehicle and vehiclebrands connected by vehicle_id. Based on the vehicle I select from the dropdown of vehicle only the brands available for that vehicle will be displayed in the second drop down. Now I have to display brand along with the release date(example: benz-2001) which is another field in vehiclebrand table . How can it be possible?

Comment: are you saying you have completed all but "Now i have to display brand along with the release date(example: benz-2001) which is another field in vehiclebrand table"

Comment: Please provide some code. How are you accessing these tables? Where is this data coming from?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to concatenate the two strings from each field on a per row basis in your dropdown. This would be done serverside though rather than in javascript. Really depends on what languages and/or framework you are using. Post some code and I'm sure you will get an answer quickly.

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(t.brand, '-', t.model) FROM table t;

Comment: coding part is completed.. two drop down with vehicle name and brand is displaying.. but i want the brand dropdown to display with release year

Comment: html part:   <td class="TitleCell"> <span class="LabelText">Vehicle</span></td> <td class="Combo_ContentCell" colspan="2"> <select name="inpVehicle"  class="Combo Combo_OneCell_width" id="inpVehicle" onchange="refreshComboBrand(); logChanges(this); return true;" autocomplete="off"><option value=""></option><div id="Vehicle_ID"></div>
 </select></td><td class="TitleCell"> <span class="LabelText">Brand</span></td>
<td class="Combo_ContentCell" colspan="2"> <select name="inpBrand"  class="Combo Combo_OneCell_width" id="inpBrand"><option value=""></option><div id="Brand_ID"></div>
</select></td>

Comment: javascript:
function refreshComboBrand() {
   var cmbJobCode = document.frmMain.inpJobCode;
  var cmbVehicle = document.frmMain.inpVehicle;
  var cmbBrand = document.frmMain.inpBrand;
  changeComboData(cmbBrand, arrBrand, cmbVehicle.options[cmbVehicle.selectedIndex].value , true);
  return true;
}

Comment: This code is actually a part of manual window creation in openbravo framework..if anyone is familliar with openbravo framework please reply back